# telnet & ping - different results

Tags: centos, mysql, ping, firewalld, telnet

I'm trying to debug a private connection between to CentOS servers

I'm trying to connect to MySQL from server 1 ( Web ) to server 2 ( MySQL )

On both I've setup the network devices with `firewalld` - added `ens10` device to `trusted` zone

On server 2 I've added `mysql` server as a service to `firewalld`

On server 1 I've opened the port `3306`

**Commands on server1**

```
$ firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --change-interface=ens10 --permanent
$ firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --permanent --add-port=3306/tcp
$ firewall-cmd --reload
```

**Commands on server2**

```
$ firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --change-interface=ens10 --permanent
$ firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-service=mysql --permanent
$ firewall-cmd --reload
```

**Debugging**

**Server 2**

```
$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN           
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:3306           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      920/mysqld          
tcp6       0      0 :::33060                :::*                    LISTEN      920/mysqld
```

And now the weird stuff ( at least for me )

**Commands from server 1**

```
$ telnet 10.0.0.4

Trying 10.0.0.4...
telnet: connect to address 10.0.0.4: No route to host # same goes for 3306 port

$ ping -c2 10.0.0.4
PING 10.0.0.4 (10.0.0.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.788 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.4: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.589 ms

--- 10.0.0.4 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 22ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.589/0.688/0.788/0.102 ms
```

What do you think is happening ?
Any ideas ?

Comment: 3306 must be open on server 2, not server 1

Comment: what is result from `firewall-cmd --list-all` on server2 ?

Comment: ```
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
  sources: 
  services: cockpit cssh dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 
```

Answer (score 1):

You get different results because they are testing different things.

Ping uses ICMP (man ping)

> ping uses the ICMP protocol's mandatory ECHO_REQUEST datagram to
> elicit an ICMP ECHO_RESPONSE from a host or gateway.  ECHO_REQUEST
> datagrams (pings) have an IP and ICMP header, followed  by  a
> struct timeval and then an arbitrary number of pad bytes used to
> fill out the packet.

Telnet on the other hand uses the TELNET protocol (normally port 23/tcp) (man telnet)

> The telnet command is used to communicate with another host using the
> TELNET protocol.

As @panki wrote you need to open port 3306 on the server where you are running the MySQL server.

Then test using `telnet 3306` from server 1.

Comment: have you read the output of `netstat` ?

Comment: @AlexanderBr. I have: it shows that MySQL is listening on port 3306 on server 2. You're post shows you have allowed incoming traffic on port 3306 on *server 1*. And since the netstat output is incomplete it does not show whether or not anything is listening on port 23 for telnet. And netstat does/can not show whether or not ICMP traffic is allowed.

Comment: I did opened it with `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-service=mysql`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with not changing the interface with `--permanent` option as well as not setting again `public` interface with `eth0`

Setting just

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --change-interface=ens10
```

without

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --change-interface=eth0
```

would cause to lose changes once `firewall-cmd --reload` was executed

thanks for your answers & comments